# How to set my own template when creating an Apex Class using Salesforce CLI?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

For `apex:class:create` there is an optional parameter `--template`:

> -t | --template TEMPLATE
>
> Optional
>
> The template to use to create the file. Supplied parameter values or default values are filled into a copy of the template.
>
> Type: string Permissible values are: ApexException, ApexUnitTest, DefaultApexClass, InboundEmailService Default value: DefaultApexClass

Either with or without DefaultApexClass value the created class has the following initial body:

```
public with sharing class MyClass {
    public MyClass () {

    }
}
```

However, there are many situations when the suggested body is not relevant and I'd like to override the template for Apex class or even provide more than one, for various cases.

Is that actually possible? I've gone through Internet and it looks like nobody has tried to investigate it so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wade Wegner has you covered. Simply install [his plugin](https://github.com/wadewegner/sfdx-code-gen), then you can create your own templates and use them using a simple sfdx command. The details are in the README file.